# Select second most minimum value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I need to write a query that selects a minimum value and it's second most minimum value from a list of integers.

Grabbing the smallest value is obvious:

```
select min(value) from table;
```

But the second smallest is not so obvious.

For the record, this list of integers is not sequential -- the min can be 1000, and the second most min can be 10000.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an analytic function

```
SELECT value
  FROM (SELECT value,
               dense_rank() over (order by value asc) rnk
          FROM table)
 WHERE rnk = 2
```

The analytic functions `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK`, and `ROW_NUMBER` are identical except for how they handle ties.  `RANK` uses a sports-style process of breaking ties so if two rows tie for a rank of 1, the next row has a rank of 3.  `DENSE_RANK` gives both of the rows tied for first place a rank of 1 and then assigns the next row a rank of 2.  `ROW_NUMBER` arbitrarily breaks the tie and gives one of the two rows with the lowest value a rank of 1 and the other a rank of 2.

Comment: +1 Same solution as I posted, but with a good additional explanation of the difference between the three similar analytical function.

Comment: Analytic functions!  Why didn't I think of them before.  I appreciate the help and the explanation.

Answer (score 7):

```
select 
  value
from
  (select 
    value, 
    dense_rank() over (order by value) rank
  from 
    table)
where
  rank = 2
```

Advantage: You can get the third value just as easy, or the bottom 10 rows (rank <= 10).

Note that the performance of this query will benefit from a proper index on 'value'.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT MIN(value)
FROM TABLE
WHERE Value > (SELECT MIN(value) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Note that this requires hitting the table twice so it will be more expensive than the analytic function solution.  As written, it is also hard to extend when you want the 3rd or the 5th or the 10th row.  You could do a COUNT(*) of the number of rows in table that have a smaller value than the current row from the outer query which is easier to extend but much less efficient.

Comment: I upvoted your solution because it is clever, but I would not use that.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select min(fine_amount) as second_min_fine_amount
from bill
where fine_amount not in (select min(fine_amount) from bill);
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Your question need additional informations. Please [edit] it or read [answer]

Comment: Pardon me, but in the SQL in the original question the name of the column is `value` and the name of the [database] table is `table`. How did `value` become `fine_amount` and `table` become `bill`? Besides, how is your answer to different to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188091/select-second-most-minimum-value-in-oracle/8188120#8188120)?

Comment: As others suggested please improve the quality of answer by adding additional details that make it helpful for visitors to understand what it does.